# Repair broken Anaconda env

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda3

My anaconda was completely broken so reinstalled it entirely. During the install I noticed that the anaconda3 file was no longer in at the root but in the "opt" folder.

So now here's the problem: there was an environment that was a particular pain to set up so I kept the "envs" folder safe, and pasted back into the "anaconda3" folder. But now jupyter notebook/lab is broken, since it is looking in:

> ~/anaconda3/etc etc

when it should be looking in

> ~opt/anaconda3/etc etc

More specifically the error I get is:

> (ENV_NAME) user:~ me$ jupyter notebook
>
> -bash: /Users/USER_NAME/opt/anaconda3/envs/ENV_NAME/bin/jupyter: /Users/USER_NAME/anaconda3/envs/ENV_NAME/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Can this be fixed without having to delete all my environments and set them all up again?

Comment: When calling jupyter do something like this `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/Users/yourname/folder1/folder2/`

Comment: It didn't work, let me edit the question with the specific error...